# What is this application build in

Tags: ms-dos, visual-c++, visual-foxpro

I got one exe ( TAS ) and many other files with .RUN, .K, .M  Extensions what are those extensions.

[image]

Is this application build using Foxpro ( which i dont think so ), VC++, C++ or Any dos based software.

The EXE opens up a blue screen with some Forms on windows.

Comment: Determing which language an application is written in requires more information than just the names of an application's files. An application can create a file with any valid name. More accurate gueses would require more information such as a list of the libraries loaded by the program, as certain common libraries might point to a specific language.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf No libraries are loaded when i run the exe it shows many forms and all operated by up and down keys on keyboard cannot use mouse also

Comment: To get a solid idea of how the application was created, you may need to analyse the executable itself with specialist tools such as a debugger, which also requires a solid knowlege of the processor and the operating system. Doing this may not be legal depending upon the license of the application. Without more information, it would be difficult for anyone to give you specific answers.

Comment: Try using a tool like "Dependency Walker" on the executable. It will show what,  if any,  libraries the executable is relying on. That may help in determining the language.